# Можно работать в Unity без знания C#?

Tags: unity3d

Я понимаю что Unity и C# взаимосвязаны, но есть возможно глупый вопрос. Я графический дизайнер, неплохо разбираюсь в Houdini, могу ли я начать работать в Unity без знания C# ? Почему задал этот вопрос. Работая в Houdini Fx тоже нужно уметь программировать, но его логика постороена таким образом, что можно использовать инструменты с полки или посредством вызова через tab без знания программирования на Vex или Python. Возможно Unity как в Houdini предусмотрел такую возможность? Спасибо Всем кто ответит.

Comment: Да думаю вполне можно начать и разобраться по ходу дела )

Comment: Благодарю за ответ

Comment: В юнити есть такой инструмент https://unity.com/ru/how-to/make-games-without-programming

Comment: Но `Houdini Fx` это не то что можно использовать в видеоиграх.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответ. Но почему Houdini нельзя использовать? Я могу в нём создать 3D окружение и экспортировать в Unity. В Houdini есть Unity plugin.

Comment: Yaroslav спасибо за https://unity.com/ru/how-to/make-games-without-programming

Comment: Нет это нельзя никак, но это если ты хочешь нормальную игру сделать.

Comment: Гудини это редактор для видео эффектов с хреналионом полигонов, неисчислимыми партикалсами по физике и до ужаса прожорливыми эффектами. В видеоигре ресурсы сильно ограничены и на все вышеперечисленное смотрят с факелами и вилами в руках. Комфортное число треугольников на экране телефонов исчисляется десятками тысяч, даже не сотнями и уж тем более не миллионами.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне возможно.
В нашей компании половина сотрудников используют Unity для худ. целей, а специальная команда разработчиков создаёт для них различные удобные инструменты.Так же в Unity существуют специальные визуальные редакторы вроде того же BOLT. Если вы хотите программировать логику, но не знаете ни одного синтаксиса языка-BOLT решение для вас. Так же, если вы работаете с графикой или хотите создавать визуальные эффекты, в Unity представлены инструменты и для этих задач, начиная от Visual и Shader Graph'ов, которые позволяют вам создавать эффекты и шейдеры по средству визуального манипулирования окошками и панельками, заканчивая мощными платными библиотеками под конкретные задачи. Вам необходимо изучить вопрос загрузки пакетов из Package Manager для установки вышеописанных плагинов, т.к. они не доступны 'из коробки' и их нужно будет догрузить.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Я программирование подтяну, но меня интересуют возможное соединение таких гигантов как Unity и Houdini, они вместе это очень сильно.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле можно.

Можно даже создавать полноценные проекты. Для этого в Unity есть множество визуальных редакторов, которые по функциональности не уступают чистому коду.
Но нужно понимать, что даже использование визуального редактора не делает разработку лёгкой, как и в случае с C#, вам нужно знать множество тонкостей движка.

Comment: Спасибо Mr.AntonDer

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ. Можно использовать Houdini для Unity https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bjikom3fJgI

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите во внимание, в разделе справки: [Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), кроме всего прочего, сказано: _являются всего лишь ссылкой на другой сайт_.
Это сообщение, пожалуйста, или поправте, или удалите.